# Adding Margin to Spinners in API 19 and lower don't work

Tags: android, android-spinner

[image]I have a spinner and after testing on api 27, there is automatically a margin set on the spinner.

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/testspinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="35dp"
        android:gravity="end"/>
```

However when testing on API 19 device, there is no longer a margin.
How do I add a margin for AP 19 and lower devices?

I have also tried changing the `Spinner` to `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner` but that doesn't add a margin.

Comment: if you mean the space between the icon and the text try  `android:paddingRight="48dp"` `android:paddingEnd="48dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a textView for your Select Role text and put it from your spinners left.At the end your layout should be like this.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Roll"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerHeader"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/spinnerHeader"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/spinnerHeader"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/spinnerHeader"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```